# yoda-time 2.3 toDateTimeAtStartOfDay() unexpected behaviour

Tags: java

Could you please explain the conditions under which Yoda time gives different result while working with same input data:

```
LocalDate value = LocalDate.now()
```

Here is what debug shows in Junit test

```
value
2015-10-16

((LocalDate) value).toDateTimeAtStartOfDay().toDate() 
Fri Oct 16 00:00:00 EEST 2015

((LocalDate) value).toDate() 
Fri Oct 16 00:00:00 EEST 2015
```

Here is what real environment debug gives (Karaf)

```
value
2015-10-16

((LocalDate) value).toDateTimeAtStartOfDay().toDate() 
Thu Oct 15 20:00:00 EDT 2015

((LocalDate) value).toDate() 
Fri Oct 16 00:00:00 EDT 2015
```

The question is why we have different results when toDateTimeAtStartOfDay() is used?

Comment: Do you mean Joda Time? I'm not aware of a library called Yoda Time, and the "J" of Joda Time is hard, as in "January".

Comment: It's also not clear whether it's actually `toDateTimeAtStartOfDay` or `toDate` which is surprising here... have you examined the result of `toDateTimeAtStartOfDay` *without* calling `toDate()`?

Comment: OP, you noticed the different time zones?